# Sniffing content of web pages in a network - experiment

Tags: proxy, sniffing

I want to sniff the web content. Don't worry, no vicious intentions, it is an experiment : )

So the scenario is: I have my host machine, and multiple guest virtual machines running on it. All VMs go to random URLs. I would like to sniff and store the *content* that the VMs access (I am interested in capturing raw HTML, I would like to skip images, video streams etc.)

One solution would be to setup a sniffer on my host machine (like *tcpdump*) and later process what is captured. The inconvenience here is that I would need to work on raw *.pcap* dumps :(

Other solution would be to setup a proxy server and configure it in the way that the content is dumped to a file... but I am no expert in proxies. Can it be done with, e.g., [squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29)?

Any other ideas?

Comment: An experiment to be used later for vicious intentions...;;-)

Comment: In the name of science! Nobody understands me! :)